# Asynchronous Server Socket missing the first buffer stream

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I'm using C# Asynchronous Server Socket and it always miss the first buffer stream. I've debugged the client and it shows no sign of missing data. I'm suspecting that the fault lies on the server but I can't seems to pinpoint the problem.

Server Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace ChatServer
{
    class TCPServer
    {
        private List<Socket> socketList;
        private const int PORT = 1337;
        private Socket serverSocket;
        const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1;
        byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        public TCPServer()
        {
            socketList = new List<Socket>();
        }

        public void Go()
        {
            SetupChat();
            StartupNetwork();
            AcceptConnections();
        }

        private void HandleDisconnections()
        {
            // throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            // throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void DumpGarbageSocket()
        {

        }

        private void ProcessMessages()
        {

        }

        private void SendToAllClients(string inMsg)
        {
            foreach (Socket clientSock in socketList)
            {
                SendMSGToClient(clientSock, inMsg);
            }
        }

        private void AcceptConnections()
        {
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(ClientSocket.BUFFER_SIZE, StartAccepting, serverSocket);
        }

        private void StartAccepting(IAsyncResult inAsyncResult)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket serverSock = (Socket)inAsyncResult.AsyncState;
                Socket clientSocket = serverSock.EndAccept(inAsyncResult);
                socketList.Add(clientSocket);
                ClientSocket cSocket = new ClientSocket();
                cSocket.clientSocket = clientSocket;
                Console.WriteLine("[SYSTEM] Socket has been connected.");
                clientSocket.BeginReceive(cSocket.buffer_stream, 0, ClientSocket.BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(StartReceiving), cSocket);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[ERROR] " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                serverSocket.BeginAccept(ClientSocket.BUFFER_SIZE, StartAccepting, serverSocket);
            }
        }

        private void StartReceiving(IAsyncResult inAsyncResult)
        {
            try
            {
                string content = String.Empty;
                ClientSocket cSocket = (ClientSocket)inAsyncResult.AsyncState;
                Socket clientSocket = cSocket.clientSocket;
                int bytesRead = clientSocket.EndReceive(inAsyncResult);
                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                    cSocket.message.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                        cSocket.buffer_stream, 0, bytesRead));

                    // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
                    // more data.
                    content = cSocket.message.ToString();
                    if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
                    {
                        // All the data has been read from the 
                        // client. Display it on the console.
                        Console.WriteLine(content.Substring(0, content.Length - 5));
                        SendToAllClients(content.Substring(0, content.Length - 5) + "<EOF>");
                        cSocket.message.Remove(0, cSocket.message.Length);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Not all data received. Get more.
                    }
                    clientSocket.BeginReceive(cSocket.buffer_stream, 0, ClientSocket.BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(StartReceiving), cSocket);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[ERROR] " + err.Message);
            }
        }

        private void SendMSGToClient(Socket inSocketToSend, string message)
        {
            byte[] dataBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
            inSocketToSend.BeginSend(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(MsgFinishSending), inSocketToSend);
        }

        private void MsgFinishSending(IAsyncResult inAsyncResult)
        {
            Socket handler = (Socket)inAsyncResult.AsyncState;
            int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(inAsyncResult);
        }

        private void StartupNetwork()
        {
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, PORT);
            Console.WriteLine("SERVER::STARTING SOCKET");
            serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            serverSocket.Bind(localEndPoint);
            serverSocket.Listen(100);
            Console.WriteLine("SERVER::BINDED");
            Console.WriteLine("SERVER::IP ADDRESS::" + localEndPoint.Address.ToString());
        }

        private void SetupChat()
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }


    }
}
```

Example: The buffer size is 10, so if I send over 'abcdefghijklmn', the server side will only receive 'klmn'. The second time I send 'abcdefghijklmn', the server side will receive the entire stream of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `BeginAccept` method you are passing in a buffer size to read and you dont handle that in your callback. Try using the `BeginAccept` method without the buffer size as **first argument**.

Answer (score 0):

You're ignoring the return value of `BeginReceive`, it's a common mistake. It's pretty likely the `BeginReceive` operation finished synchronously, in which case, the callback isn't invoked at all.

Try something like this:

```
var result = clientSocket.BeginReceive
             (
               cSocket.buffer_stream, 0, ClientSocket.BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, 
               new AsyncCallback(StartReceiving), cSocket
             );

if (result.CompletedSynchronously) StartReceiving(result);
```

It's pretty handy to code this as an extension method on `IAsyncResult` (use `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke` if appropriate). Or, even better, start using the new `Task`-based asynchronous APIs - this turns all this boiler plate to a simple `await ReceiveAsync` (or better, with `TcpClient`, `ReadAsync`).